# NuGet restore with latest version

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

Referring a NuGet package with the version of 1.0.1 from our local NuGet feed. Later pushed the next version of package 1.0.2. When using NuGet restore or update it works well.

Removed the older NuGet package of version 1.0.1 but the package.config still referring the version 1.0.1.

Now, NuGet restore looking the version 1.0.1. It can't upgraded to 1.0.2 (or latest version which available).

Included the **allowedVersions** in package.config with

```
<package id="packagename" version="1.0.1" allowedVersions="[1,)" />
```

Can you suggest to install the latest package if mentioned version not available in corresponding feed?

Answer (score 1):

`packages.config` only allows a single version of a package to be specified. In your case you will need to [update the package using the package manager UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#updating-a-package) in VS or the [Update-Package command in the package manager console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console#updating-a-package).

The `allowedVersions`attribute only prevents these two methods from upgrading beyond the specified version range.

Comment: thanks. Here I found the allowedVersions used to get range if specified version not found.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/packages-config 

Daily, we pushing the packages. So, we can't define the single version as well we can't keep the older version packages due to storage.

Is there any possible to restore the latest version if package not found in the source?